# Having a loop in a relationship ER modelling

Tags: entity-relationship

Using Chen's notation on an entity relationship model, for database design. Is this the correct way to illustrate the following relation. 'Many employees report to one employee':

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below image would be more approapraiate

[image]

**[E-R Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)**

**[DATA MODEL](http://www.edrawsoft.com/datamodel.php)**

**[STACK SIMILAR QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896699/one-to-many-relationships-in-er-diagram)**

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the diamond. You can have the direct relationship. Unless the relationship itself has attributes, the diamond is not used.

Comment: This is from a school past paper and the diamond was there so i think its meant to be used. Is this still correct though?